# Selecting data from var_dump?

Tags: php, database

I ran a `var_dump` on my variable that is a list of information, here is the result of the `var_dump`

```
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(3) "top" ["value"]=> string(4) "100%" }
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "left" ["value"]=> string(3) "Gus" }
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "text" ["value"]=> string(4) "Hank" }
```

How do I get the value of the `[name]` => `"top"` (`[value]` here is 100%)so on and so forth?

Here is the PHP

```
foreach ($field['options'] as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<div style="color: #fff;">';
                    echo '<li style="color: #fff;">'.var_dump ($value).'</li>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

To get `"top"` I tried `$value['top']` just like `$field['options']` gets the options array, how do I break it down to get each speific option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mis-use `var_dump($value)` .

Assume `$field['options']` is the array you `var_dump` at the beginning, you can just use `$value['name']` instead of `var_dump($value)`.

To find specific value, use something like `if($value['name'] === 'top')` in the foreach loop

*Sidenote:* The function `var_dump()` is to print the variable content. To get it inline / into a variable, use `var_export($variable, true)`.

Comment: Ok instead of listing all of them how do I echo a specific name ex. top? because `$value['name']` returns all the names, do I need another foreach.. not really sure..

Comment: I was just using var_dump to analyze the array.. what I am asking is with the returned results how do I select specific values?

Comment: Use `$value['name']` and `$value['value']` should be fine. Since you're using foreach loop, you iterate all values in the array. To find specific value, use something like `if($value['name'] === 'top')` in the foreach loop

Comment: How do I break it down to just return one value, not all of em... for example just the top?

Comment: ooo ok, thanks... very nice of you :) WAIT... that doesnt return the value does it? I tried to echo that and it returns nothing..

Answer (score 1):

Use `$value['name']` and `$value['value']` to get the respective values.

Comment: Same for @Shivan Raptor, this returns all of them.. how do I return a specific one